# Is there any way to get date from ObjectId from mongoose using aggregate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have `Users` Collection. `devices` are all in array of Objects.

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c66a979e109fe0f537c7e37"),
    "devices": [{
            "dev_token" : "XXXX",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ccc0fa5f7778412173d22bf")
        }]

},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c66b6382b18fc4ff0276dcc"),
    "devices": [{
            "dev_token" : "XXXX",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c93316cc33c622bdcfaa4be")
        }]

}]
```

I need to query the documents with adding the new field `date` in `devices`  like

```
"devices": [{
       "dev_token" : "XXXX",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c93316cc33c622bdcfaa4be"),
       "date": ISODate("2012-10-15T21:26:17Z")
}]
```

`date` key from  `devices._id.getTimestamp()`

I tried using aggregate this one, donno how to use `getTimestamp()`

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([ {
    "$unwind": "$devices"
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "devices": {
                "$push": "$devices._id.getTimestamp()"
          }
     }
}])
```

I use `$devices._id.getTimestamp()`, this could be error.. Here how I handle this one.. Thanks for advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) to get Timestamp from the _id field.

Add `date` field to each `devices` element after `unwind` stage, using [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)

Try this :

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([ {
    "$unwind": "$devices"
},{
    $addFields : {
        "devices.date": { $toDate: "$_id" }
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "devices": {
                "$push": "$devices"
          }
     }
}])
```

You can check the result at [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6Y0YWwzCMOr) (just press "run")

Comment: Yeah but `$toDate` is in mongodb >4.0. Can't use in MongoDB 3.6 Version. any other options?

Comment: I tried finding a way which can be used in case of MongoDB 3.6, but i'm unable to find any way. I will look more and update answer if i find something.

Comment: Thank you for your response. if there is no way, will do it in js

Answer (score 3):

### Using MongoDb 3.6

The [`$dateFromParts`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/) operator comes in handy here where you can use it in conjunction with the other date operators. You won't need
to `$unwind` the array as you can use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to map over the `devices` array documents and add the extra date field with the above expression.

This can be followed with an example pipeline below :

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([    
    { "$addFields": {
        "devices": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$devices",
                "in": {
                    "dev_token": "$$this.dev_token",
                    "_id": "$$this._id",
                    "date": {
                        "$dateFromParts": {
                            'year': { "$year": "$$this._id"}, 
                            'month': { "$month": "$$this._id"}, 
                            'day':{ "$dayOfMonth": "$$this._id"},
                            'hour': { "$hour": "$$this._id"}, 
                            'minute': { "$minute": "$$this._id"}, 
                            'second': { "$second": "$$this._id"},
                            'millisecond': { "$millisecond": "$$this._id"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } }
])
```

**Output**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c66a979e109fe0f537c7e37"),
    "devices" : [ 
        {
            "dev_token" : "XXXX",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ccc0fa5f7778412173d22bf"),
            "date" : ISODate("2019-05-03T09:53:41.000Z")
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c66b6382b18fc4ff0276dcc"),
    "devices" : [ 
        {
            "dev_token" : "XXXX",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c93316cc33c622bdcfaa4be"),
            "date" : ISODate("2019-03-21T06:38:36.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

---

### Using MongoDb 4.0 and newer:

The pipeline can be tweaked slightly to use the new [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) or [`$convert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#exp._S_convert) operators. Their respective uses follow:

[**`$toDate`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/)

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([    
    { "$addFields": {
        "devices": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$devices",
                "in": {
                    "dev_token": "$$this.dev_token",
                    "_id": "$$this._id",
                    "date": { "$toDate": "$$this._id" }
                }
            }
        }
    } }
])
```

[**`$convert`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/#exp._S_convert)

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([    
    { "$addFields": {
        "devices": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$devices",
                "in": {
                    "dev_token": "$$this.dev_token",
                    "_id": "$$this._id",
                    "date": { 
                        "$convert": { "input": "$$this._id", "to": "date" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } }
])
```